# I would like to take more than one slideshow from this to one page

Tags: javascript, html, slideshow

I have a code, a simple automatic slideshow. I would like to place more than 1 slideshow, but they will overwrite each other. Please help me how can i solve this. Please help me to solve this problem. I would like to use these slideshows on the same page, but when a i try only 1 slideshow works. I would like to use 8 types of this slideshow in the future. And 1 extra, i would like to place a simple animation between the pics when they switch.
html:

```
<div class="pic-wrapper">
<img name="slide" width="400" height="377" object-fit="cover"/>
</div>
```

and

```
<div class="pic-wrapper">


<img name="slide2" width="400" height="377" object-fit="cover"/>

</div>
```

and my javascripts:

```
<script>
    var i = 0;          // Start Point
var images = [];    // Images Array
var time = 3000;    // Time Between Switch

// Image List
images[0] = "img/kosar/kosar1.jpg";
images[1] = "img/kosar/kosar2.jpg";
images[2] = "img/kosar/kosar3.jpg";
images[3] = "img/kosar/kosar4.jpg";

// Change Image
function changeImg(){
    document.slide2.src = images[i];

    // Check If Index Is Under Max
    if(i < images.length - 1){
      // Add 1 to Index
      i++; 
    } else { 
        // Reset Back To O
        i = 0;
    }

    // Run function every x seconds
    setTimeout("changeImg()", time);
}

// Run function when page loads
window.onload=changeImg;
</script>
```

and

```
<script>
    var i = 0;          // Start Point
var images = [];    // Images Array
var time = 3000;    // Time Between Switch

// Image List
images[0] = "img/roplabda/ropi1.jpg";
images[1] = "img/roplabda/ropi2.jpg";
images[2] = "img/roplabda/ropi3.jpg";
images[3] = "img/roplabda/ropi4.jpg";

// Change Image
function changeImg(){
    document.slide.src = images[i];

    // Check If Index Is Under Max
    if(i < images.length - 1){
      // Add 1 to Index
      i++; 
    } else { 
        // Reset Back To O
        i = 0;
    }

    // Run function every x seconds
    setTimeout("changeImg()", time);
}

// Run function when page loads
window.onload=changeImg;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you merge your script into something like this ?

```
var slide1 = 0;          // First Slide index
var slide2 = 0;  //Second Slide Index
var images = [];    // Images Array
var time = 3000;    // Time Between Switch

// Image List
imageObjects = { 'firstSlide': [
"img/roplabda/ropi1.jpg",
"img/roplabda/ropi2.jpg",
"img/roplabda/ropi3.jpg",
"img/roplabda/ropi4.jpg",
], 
'secondSlide': [
 "img/kosar/kosar1.jpg",
 "img/kosar/kosar2.jpg",
 "img/kosar/kosar3.jpg",
 "img/kosar/kosar4.jpg"
]};


// Change Image
function changeImg(){
    document.slide.src = imageObjects.firstSlide[slide1];
        document.slide2.src = imageObjects.secondSlide[slide2];
    // Check If Index Is Under Max
    if(slide1 < imageObjects.firstSlide.length - 1){
      // Add 1 to Index
      slide1++; 
    } else { 
        // Reset Back To O
        slide1 = 0;
    }
    if(slide2 < imageObjects.secondSlide.length - 1){
      // Add 1 to Index
      slide2++; 
    } else { 
        // Reset Back To O
        slide2 = 0;
    }

    // Run function every x seconds
    setTimeout("changeImg()", time);
}

// Run function when page loads
window.onload=changeImg;
```

If you really want to keep separate scripts for these slideshow, for whatever reason. Then you should probably keep your variables names of "i" & "images" unique and not repeat them in next script.

Comment: Thanks it works, and how can i add a simple transition between the slide changes?

Comment: That isn't possible with document.slide.src = imageObjects.firstSlide[slide1]; 
You'll have to have all the images loaded first for transitions between them. Look up some tutorial on making slider, there are plenty of them.